# Is it memory efficient to reassign a variable or create a new one in python?

Tags: python, variables

For example. Here's a simple code that removes the punctuation from a string. ('  ,  .)

```
s = "Hello, I'm Codemaker."
x = list(s)
for i in x:
    if ord(i) == 39 or ord(i) == 44 or ord(i) == 46:
        x.pop(x.index(i))
# Should I reassign the same variable for more efficiency ?
# x = ''.join(x)

# Or assign a new one ?
# y = ''.join(x)
```

The same can apply for the variable "x". I could just reassign "s" into a list, do the operations and then convert it back to a string.

The code would be like this:

```
s = "Hello, I'm Codemaker."
s = list(s)
for i in s:
    if ord(i) == 39 or ord(i) == 44 or ord(i) == 46:
        s.pop(s.index(i))
s = ''.join(s)
```

I want to know which one is more efficient.

Comment: Moving the old variable out of scope makes it eligible for garbage collection. *However*, if you were doing this in a function and the variable were function-local, it would be GCable on function exit anyhow, making the difference effectively meaningless in well-structured code.

Comment: The bigger concern is readability. When you reassign a variable with a value of a different type, a human reading the code then needs to keep both the assignments in mind to know what something is at any given point in time.

Comment: The whole run-time is going to be the `.index` and `.pop`... and popping a list you're iterating over is never a good idea...

Comment: `x = list(s)`, no need to use a list comprehension. Don't alter the list while you loop over it. Better use a list comprehension to just filter: `s = ''.join([c for c in s if ord(c) not in {39, 44, 46}])`. Better still: use the `str.translate()` method, which lets you remove characters using a loop in C. `s.translate(dict.fromkeys((39, 44, 46}))`.

Comment: Memory efficient? You're worrying about the wrong things, considering you've got an incredibly slow `s.pop(s.index(i))`, *while iterating over `s`*.

Comment: So it's not _That_ big of a difference ? I can just focus on readability.

Comment: you can iterate over a string by characters without making an extra list at all, which would be more memory efficient than tweaking your code into unreadability by pointless reuse of variable names.

Comment: And you really do not need to worry about memory for one or two small lists.

Comment: Readability and correctness should *absolutely* take precedence over attempting microoptimizations. As should algorithm-level optimizations. It's far, far better to implement a good algorithm than to implement a bad algorithm in an optimal manner.

Comment: Ideally, you'd use `s.translate(str.maketrans('', '', "',."))`...

Comment: Martijn Pieters I just brought this code as an example. I was just curious about how reassigning and creating new variables compare in memory efficiency.

Comment: Cases where memory efficiency *actually matters* (within the set of domains where Python is the right tool for the job) almost never look like this. They center around things like cache expiration policy, or perhaps using the right data structure for the job (a packed array of values a la numpy, for example, vs a Python list). If you're focusing on this kind of example to try to teach yourself to write memory-efficient code, you're Doing It Wrong.

Comment: Charles Duffy Well...what can I do to do it right ?

Comment: Find a real-world example of a place where you have problems, to start. Use a memory profiler to track down where the problem comes from. That might be an object following a registry pattern that isn't using lazy references, it might be a place where you've got a cache with no expiration policy, it might be... whatever. Fix that problem, based on where the memory profiler told you it was. Find another problem, repeat, &c.

Comment: One memorable case from over a decade ago (dealing with memory issues in CSCVS, a tool for intuiting changesets from CVS repository history) was resolved by no longer trying to implement my own datastore, but farming the work of tracking a large amount of content out to SQLite -- which, by virtue of indexing that content, didn't need to keep the whole dataset in memory at once. That's kinda' my point -- good memory management isn't something you can do by virtue of *how you write your code*; rather, it's part of *how you design your programs*, and thus, what code you choose to write.

Comment: Charles Duffy I'll keep that in mind. I'm pretty new to programming (less than a year) but I'm very excited to learn.

Answer (score 0):

**update: rephrasing**

If you are looking for a more compact way that is more readable. Why not simply do this?

```
''.join(i for i in s if ord(i) not in [39,44,46])
```

Or (after discussion/suggestion with Jon C. below)

```
excludechars = "',."
''.join(i for i in s if i not in excludechars)
```

Comment: @JonClements True, I phrased myself wrong. When I write Python code I want it to look neat and simple (speed is not the concern). This might not be the quickest way but it is easy to read.

Comment: Okay... but in that case why still use `ord()` and codes... surely just using the characters themselves would assist in readability of what this does?

Comment: Okay... I was just picking up on *easy to read*... which `if i not in ",'."` imho is more so and by nature automatically avoids the function call... but anyway...

Comment: @JonClements You are right there. Updating answer now.

Comment: Why the `list()` - might as well keep it a string if you're not going to make it a set... there's nothing gained there from making it a list...

Answer (score 0):

When you "re-assign" a variable its old value is "freed" albeit not instantaneously but at the mercy of garbage collector. So, yes, if you do not need the old value you can save memory by "re-assigning" a variable a new value. However, you can do the same without re-asigning:

```
y = ''.join(x)
del x
```

True, it appears that temporarily you hold two values in the memory but the same is true if you re-assign to the same variable, especially due to the nature of the garbage collection and also because you cannot free old value before you "completely" created the new value.

Comment: Well, assigning `x` to a new value won't necessarily free memory if the value previously referenced by `x` happens to be referenced from elsewhere...

Comment: @JonClements Well, I should have added "assuming it can be garbage collected" in my answer which is a valid assumption for the example code shown in OP. In addition, _"... "freed" albeit not instantaneously but at the mercy of garbage collector"_ implies that garbage collector may not free a variable right away (for whatever reason - timing or reference count or any other reason).

Answer (score -1):

The second one appears to be more efficent although it is not important for simple programs but make sure that you delete all variables which are no longer required.